# QNAP 669Pro RAID 0 (striping volume) mountable

Tags: raid-0, qnap

I just bought a 669pro. Installed 3 3TB disks. Two of them I configured as RAID 0(Don't know what I was thinking) Striping volume (6 TB). I copied 3 TB of data to the disks, no problems. It was working fine. Then (probably due to my own fault, I was fooling around with LFTP, I think It was downloading something of my PVR via FTP, whereto I'm not sure), The 669 was giving this fault message by mail, but was still functioning normally:

Server Name: QNAP669
IP Address: 192.168.2.20
Date/Time: 2013/01/13 17:05:51
Level:  Error
The system is unable to save your settings (file = [/etc/storage.conf], section = [VOLUME 1], field = [status], value = [-6]) due to insufficient ramdisk space. If restarting the server does not solve the problem please contact support for further assistance.

So I restarted the NAS and all of a sudden it had lost all it's setting and was asking to be formatted again. I Didn't do that of course, I turned it off and removed the first disk and inserted another one. It now still sees the raid 0 striping volume but it is unmounted.

I did not save the settings before

Can this problem be fixed???

Can the raid be restored or are all the data lost, I don't have a backup of these data

Is it possible to mount the striping volume? (the Qnap still sees it and recognizes it as striping volume)

Comment: If you have sufficient space (with 6TB doubtful, but still...) take out both drives and create an image of them. That way you can restore to the current bad situation without fear of making things worse while attempting to recover. Next put the drives in a desktop and check how they are formatted. If you are lucky it will be in a format that you can recreate in the desktop.  Post the output of that format here in your post.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

This started to happen with latest firmware update (version 4.0.x)

I think there is some process who is filling the ramdrive mounted on root, until is totally filled up. In fact this is what I see:

```
# df
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/ram0               139.5M    139.4M      3.0k 100% /
```

In beginning I thought that there is some log file filling up all the 139MB of the ram drive, then I started to look around all the folders in in the root to see which one is filled by what, and the result is quite interesting.

What I found on my system is that there is directory located at `/share/Qdownload` that is filled with files downloaded by the Downloading Station, which is mounted on the ramdrive. It  shouldn't be there: in fact it should be located in `/share/MD0_DATA/Qdownload`, since `/share/MD0_DATA/` points to the real hard drive, while `/share/Qdownload` gets stored in the ramdrive...

So basically there, in my case, the download station is downloading files in the ramdrive, instead of the real hard drive. This fills the ramdrive, and then everything breaks.

To fix the issue, I need to set the Download Station application to move the completed files into some directory located in a directory located on the actual hard disks. For your case, I suggest you to ssh into your nas, try to find which directory is filling the ramdrive and trac  the cause (command `du -h`).

Most probably it's a problem with the same bug with the Download Station. Try creating two shared folders and call them "Downloading" and "Completed", and configure your Download Station to use these two folders to store downloads which are in progress or completed:

[image]

This will prevent the Download Station to fill up the ramdrive.

After doing this change, reboot your system, so the ramdrive will be cleaned up.

I think that also Qsync app may have the same issue, since I can see I have a `/share/Qsync` folder, which I think it's wrong.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

More simple way to solve this is to create a Logical link in the share/MD0_DATA
[MD0_DATA]#ln -sf /share/MD0_DATA/Qdownloadstation /share/Qdownloadstation
All data what's trying to get stored in /share/Qdownloadstation will be redirected to /share/MD0_DATA/Qdownloadstation.

Comment: It's a little tricky to see where commands start and end here. Could you please [edit] your answer to improve the formatting?